# Simple program for trimming video

Tags: windows

I have a video of a concert, and a list of timestamps (5:06-15:49, 17:56-29:14...) that correspond to songs I would like to make into separate videos. Can anyone recommend a simple program I can use to do this? The one built into windows is troublesome to use and I can only make one clip at a time.

Comment: Hi - it might help if you say what file format your original files are in?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the format you have your video, one option is VirtualDub2.
It is a free linear editor, but it is good to trim a video without recompression.

Go to the Video Menu and choose direct stream copy. Do the same with the audio.

You need to do it one by one. Make a backup first. Open the video, cut the end of it first so you do not need to recalculate the timing and then cut the start of it, and save with a different name.

If you want to automate it and you are fine with command lines, try FFmpeg.
https://www.google.com/search?q=ffmpeg+batch+trim+video

If you need to do a bit more, like adding fade in and out, and control a bit more the trimming, you can use a free nonlinear editor, but most of them will recompress the video. Davinci Resolve, Hit Film Express, Open Shot for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you re-encode them, you might lose quality. Is there any software for video that allows splitting of a video file without re-rendering? For mp3 audio you can use mp3direct to split mp3 files without re-encoding. The resulting files will be as good as the original was.

Answer (score -1):

The quickest, dirtiest way of doing this would be using Windows Movie Maker. The program is easy to use, free and terrible, but totally fit for what you're trying to do.

If you're looking for (free) alternatives, try:

- test version of Sony Vegas
- test version of Adobe Premiere
- test version of Camtasia (eugh)
- free version of Davinci Resolve (a bit more advanced)

Comment: windows movie maker doesnt really exist anymore as far as i can tell. thanks for the help though!

Comment: Jeez, really? Damn I feel old :D

Comment: I will second the free version of DaVinci Resolve. It can seem a little overwelming but there are plenty of tutorials on You Tube to get you started. Blackmagic Design also provides very low cost and in many cases free training resources.